# store every digit of a number in a arr by using a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, numbers

I am trying to write a function to save all the digits of any given number in an array by using the recursive method, but it stops at the first digit and the looping is no work, can someone tell me what I did wrong?

```
function digit(n) {
   var arr = [];
   if (n < 10) {
       return arr.push(n);
   } else {
       var dig = n % 10;
       arr.push(dig);
       digit(Math.floor(n / 10));
   }
   return arr;
}
```

Comment: Is it a requirment to use a recursive function for that task, because there are _easier_ ways splite a number to digits.

Answer (score 1):

Because you reset `arr` to an empty array each time, it never gets anywhere.  You need to store it outside the recursive function and return it at the end.

```js
function digit(d) {
    var arr = [];
    
    function store_digit(n) {
      if (n < 10) {
          return arr.push(n);
      } else {
          var dig = n % 10;
          arr.push(dig);
          store_digit(Math.floor(n / 10));
      }
    }
    
    store_digit(d);
    console.log(arr)
    return arr;
}

digit(682)
```

Comment: `Array#push` returns the new length of the array, not the array itself.

Comment: @wilusdaman -- Good catch.  I'm just borrowing the syntax in the original post-- nothing is actually ever assigned to what is returned from `store_digit`.  But you're correct-- while it would be a shorthand for `arr.push(n); return;` it is unnecessary since the function now contains only an `if` and an `else` block, so it will exit as soon as the `if` executes anyway.

Comment: actually you need no inner function for genrating the array.

Comment: Sure, fair point-- I was trying to match the poster's original code as the question states they're trying to "[use] the recursive method". But you're of course correct that there are other ways to solve this that might be more succinct and/or more expressive.

Answer (score 0):

recursion is correct but you are not using the returned values correctly, you will only return the last digit the way you are doing, you need to concat arrays returned from the successive method calls. something like this seems to work:

```js
function digit(n){
   var arr = [];
   if(n<10){
      arr.push(n);
   }else{
      var dig = n % 10;
      arr.push(dig);
      arr = arr.concat(digit(Math.floor(n /10)));
   }
   return arr;
}
console.log(digit(999));
```

Comment: @Sen123 you are welcome, consider accepting the answer if it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The code is running through all the digits. Since you are initializing the array each time your function runs, it's just returning the last run digit.

Try this one:

```
var arr = [];
function digit(n) {
  if (n < 10) {
    return arr.push(n);
  }
  else {
    var dig = n % 10;
    arr.push(dig);
    digit(Math.floor(n / 10));
  }
}
digit(123456789)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a global variable for such a task. It e.g. would fail if you use the function twice if you don't reset the `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
digit(123456);

function digit(n) {
   var arr = [];
   if (n < 10) {
       arr.push(n);
   } else {      
    numberToString = n.toString();

    for (var i = 0, len = numberToString.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        arr.push(+numberToString.charAt(i));
    }

      console.log(arr);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers given so far have got the right idea. Here's that idea expressed a little more simply:

```
function digits(n, result=[]){
    return n < 10
      ? result.concat([n]).reverse()
      : digits(Math.floor(n / 10), result.concat([n % 10]);
}

digits(1234); //=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can remove the `.reverse()` if the expected output goes smallest order to greatest order rather than greatest to smallest.

[demo](https://repl.it/JilG)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a clean approach, where every call of the function returns a valid part result.

At start you define the [recursion temination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination), which is given if the value of `n` is smaller than `10`. In this case you return an array with the value.

In all other cases, you return the result of the recursion call of the integer value of `n` divided by `10` and concat the rest of a division by `10`.

This proposal does not use another explicit temporary variable.

```js
function getDigits(n) {
    if (n < 10) {
        return [n];
    }
    return getDigits(Math.floor(n / 10)).concat(n % 10);
}

console.log(getDigits(123456));
```

For a more concise style, you could use a ternary with the same idea as above.

```js
function getDigits(n) {
    return n < 10 ? [n] : getDigits(Math.floor(n / 10)).concat(n % 10);
}

console.log(getDigits(123456));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the spread operator:

```
function getDigits(num, radix = 10) {
    return num < radix ?
        [num] :
        [...getDigits(Math.floor(num / radix), radix), (num % radix)];
}
getDigits(0xCAFEBABE, 0x10);
// ==> [12,  10,  15,  14,  11,  10,  11,  14]
```

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
var arr = [];

function digit(n){

   if (n<10) {
        return arr.push(n);
   } else {
     var dig = n % 10;
     arr.push(dig);
     digit(Math.floor(n /10));
   }
   return arr;

}
```

Comment: put arr outside

Comment: Using a global variable here is a bad idea because you need to remeber that you have to reset this variable each time you call the function. Such a setup is error prone and should not be used.